# Can't find 8080 port. (Docker, docker-compose) Error

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I think this is a proxy issue because I can still connect to 8380 with localhost domain. But the error is different.

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

Here is my docker-compose file. I set up docker overlay network but it doesn't help either. I think this is proxy issue.

```
version: '3'

services:
    testidpsaml:
        image: kristophjunge/test-saml-idp
        environment:
            - SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ENTITY_ID=urn:asdasd
            - SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ASSERTION_CONSUMER_SERVICE=http://localhost:8446/login/callback
        ports:
            - 8380:8080
            - 8333:8443
    saml-enabled-reverse-proxy:
        build: ./saml-enabled-reverse-proxy
        ports:
            - 8446:8446
        networks:
            - my_net
    app:
        build: ./adssa
        volumes:
            - /Users/jbaek:/asd/src
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        networks:
            - my_net

networks:
    my_net:
```

In application,,,

```
...

var samlStrategy = new saml.Strategy({
// config options here
    callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:8446/login/callback', //we don't use this?
    // 8380 WORKS? WHY? WHY I CAN'T Connect 
    entryPoint: 'http://localhost:8380/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php', 
    ...
app.get('/',
    function(req, res) {
        apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serviceProvider});
    }
);
...

var server = app.listen(8446, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
>   them at a hostname identical to the container name.

So in your case all the services `testidpsaml,saml-enabled-reverse-proxy`  ... will be on single network.

And you can access 1 service from another service using hostname as servicename.

eg:  To access your app service inside testidpsaml

```
http://app:8080/contextpath/apipath
```

When you define port `8380:8080` it means you are forwarding 8080 from container to 8380 in Host.

Same app service will be available in host as

```
http://app:8380/contextpath/apipath
```

**Please change your entryPoint accordingly.**

You can read more about [Networking here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Answer (score 1):

When you define `ports:- 8380:8080`, it will publish `testidpsaml`'s `8080` port to host's `8380` port. Then, on docker host(not container), you can visit it with `localhost:8380`.

But, in `app` service, your code is running in container, then `localhost` not mean the `docker host`, but the current container, you could specify replace `localhost` with your `docker host ip` to make it work.

In fact, you could also directly specify the service name, because compose will setup [a custom network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) for you:

> User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.

in which it has a internal dns server, which could help container find eathother quickly, no need to use docker host to pass traffic container. For your case, use next:

```
entryPoint: 'http://testidpsaml:8080/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php'
```